# Centering multiple tables in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm new to HTML & CSS. I made multiple tables and wish to display them all on one line inside a box. I tried the following but this doesn't seem to work. Can someone please fix this? 
This is my CSS code:

```
#content2{
   margin: 30px 0;
   background: white;
   padding: 20px;
   clear: both;
   box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #999;
   text-align: center;
   overflow:hidden;

}

table{
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  float:left;
}
td,th{
  padding: 20px;
}
```

The HTML should be correct.

Comment: float:left; wont use for a table

Comment: Can you make it a plunker or a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `float: left`, display the tables as inline by using `display: inline-block`

[Example](http://jsbin.com/eqOSigU/1/edit?html,css,output)

Do know that this will make it so `table` elements won't get their default full width (which you probably don't want to begin with).

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options that im aware of.

1 . If you want it pure CSS and "dynamic" (i.e. you dont know the width beforehand) you can set the table to `display: inline-block` and remove your float. This works in chrome, but you may have issues with IE, especially older versions.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZfX2M/

2 . If you know the width then set an inner content div with that width, and `margin:auto` it.

http://jsfiddle.net/AuF7z/1/

3 . if you don't know the width, but your happy to use JS, then do the same as above, but calculate the width in JS (i use jQuery as its what im used to, but you could use raw JS)

http://jsfiddle.net/mVADm/1/